# VGA cable causing resolution issue

Tags: troubleshooting, cable, vga

I recently bought a new VGA cable. When connected, Windows 7 detects my monitor as a generic plug and play monitor. The resolution goes bad with the screen blurred. This problem disappears when I connect my original VGA cable. Also Windows 7 detects my LG monitor correctly in this case.

I am pretty sure it is something to do with the VGA cable but have no idea what could be the possible issue.

Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new VGA cable is probably bad.  VGA is analog so it's possible to get a partial signal even if part of the cable is broken.  Get a new VGA cable, the one you got was likely junk.

Comment: Don't buy cheap cables for anything, really. You don't really need a $1000 cable, but the $1 cable has probably been used, stepped on, backed over, you get my point.

Comment: Yes, always make sure the cable is fully shielded. I've had cables that function fully, but give **terrible** ghosting and blur issues because they weren't fully shielded.

Comment: Thnx to all. Will get a new cable and check if the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the pins in the vga are straight, sometimes when they are bend, they dont display image well too.