# External monitor with Macbook - resolution not available?

Tags: mac, macbook, display, resolution

I'm using an external monitor with my MacBook Pro 13 inch. The external monitor is a Dell 1650x1080 resolution.

I'm connecting using a mini display port to DVI adaptor.

On a previous MacBook Pro 13 inch, I plugged the monitor in and the resolution appeared in the list of Display options.

However, now when I go to Display, the resolution simply does not appear, so I'm running it at the wrong resolution. There doesn't seem to be a way to enter a custom resolution.

I was hoping [this solution](https://superuser.com/questions/193703/resolution-1920-x-1080-is-not-available-for-external-monitor) might work - but it doesn't.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have the same monitor, cable, and adapter?