# How do I set 1920 x 1200 resolution when monitor is connected via D-Sub cable?

Tags: display, intel-graphics

Native resolution of my monitor is 1920 x 1200; however, when I connect it via a D-Sub cable, I can't choose this resolution. Only 1920 x 1080 and 2048 x 1152 are available. How can I make my native resolution available?

UPS I'm using Windows 8.1 x64. Monitor is detected as Generic Non-PnP. My monitor drivers installation says that the monitor is not found (I guess because it's connected via an analog cable)

UPD2 I've installed Dell monitor drivers forcibly, but the native resolution still is not available in the resolution selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most probably because of a bad cable so that the OS cannot read the information about the monitor, hence not recognize it's native resolution. It's not related to analog or digital because VGA cable is capable of transferring images up to 2048×1536@85Hz. I've seen this many times on my friends' computer and after replacing it with a better cable, the problem is solved.

Another way is creating a customized resolution your own. Many graphics card drivers support this. It's rather tricky as there are many parameters like pixel clock, refresh rate... to take care of.

[image: NVIDIA custom resolution]

Comment: Is it impossible to override cable's resolution info?

Comment: I don't know if there is any way to do that but there's another way you can try

Comment: I have Intel HD graphics (not nVidia) and it seems that feature is locked.

Comment: try borrowing a good cable from someone and see if it solves your problem

Comment: +1 for bad cable. The *reason* the OP cannot select the correct resolution is because the computer isn't getting DDC data from the monitor.