# Windows loses window position on large monitor

Tags: windows-10, 4k-resolution

I have recently purchased a 4k monitor (3840 x 2160 pixels at 60 Hz). I have noticed that if the monitor turns off (e.g. when the screen turn off for power saving triggered by activity timeout), all my windows show up in the top left quarter of the screen, as if I had a 1920 x 1080 monitor.

What is the reason for this and how can I fix it?

I am running Windows 10 x64 Pro. My monitor is a Philips BDM4350, connected to the PC via DisplayPort 1.2.
I have updated the monitor driver to use the manufacturer's driver.

It seems this is something that has been happening in Windows since 2009

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4d8f3aef-8c04-481b-a69a-ec0fbf3669c2/turning-off-display-resizes-open-windows

http://forum.cakewalk.com/SOLVED-Losing-windows-positions-when-HDMI-monitor-back-from-sleep-m3485290.aspx

Update: I have upgraded to Windows 11, and the problem went away. However, for work I log in remotely into a Windows 10 virtual machine, and when my home PC times out, my remote Win10 session loses the position of the windows. This used to happen on the local as well as the remote Win10 sessions. Now local session is Win11, which remembers window sizes and positions. Remote session is Win10, and it still has the problem.

Comment: " have noticed that if the PC locks up"  - Try sorting out why this occurs and correct the problem. I think the desktop is reverting temporarily to the native resolution. So correcting the problem will correct the resolution (upgrade BIOS, Chipset, Video and power drivers)

Comment: [Opened windows shift to primary display whenever the LCD is turned off](https://superuser.com/q/1347847/241386)

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue too.

When the monitor turns off, Windows sets the resolution to the standard (which is used at logon). This moves all your windows into the available space.
Log on once as admin, and set the screen resolution correctly (to the new higher one). Then save it as 'default' for new users and the logon screen. Afterwards, the issue should be gone.

Comment: Did that, and it has not fixed the issue. I even went through the registry and modified all resolutions I could find to 3840 x 2160.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this post when researching a solution for a problem with my multi-monitor setup. During my research I came across the Custom Resolution Utility (https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU) that may help with the issue described here.