# Why is Windows only able to send 4:3 output on 16:9 monitor?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, aspect-ratio

Windows only sends a 4:3 output to a 16:9 monitor. It detects the monitor as generic, and only provides the 1024x768 resolution as maximum, while the monitor's menu recommends to set it as 1360x768. However it has no trouble to display the primary screen:

[image]

[image]

Do you have any idea?

Comment: are you using the VGA port? [buy a better cable](https://superuser.com/a/1356566/241386)

Comment: that's weird, because that's the new one and I have to change to an old one. Anyway, make it an answer and I'll accept it. Also, if you have further information about why the image wire is still OK while the monitor information one is broken then it would be great